# Data Formulation

Tags: arrays, database, function, google-sheets, google-query-language

I am hoping to get some help formulating an array to more concisely view my data coming in from a google form. Is this something someone can help me with? I'm slightly familiar, but the function to do this is going to be quite complicated, I'm afraid.

On my Google form, I have a question that people may or may not fill out multiple times. In order to let them do that, I've had to copy the question repeatedly on the form. If they need to keep answering the question, they continue down the copied versions. If they're done, they select "no," and are directed to finish the form.

On my intake spreadsheet, this data comes through as about 30 different columns to account for each of the copied versions of that question. I'm hoping to order the columns that are filled out and then delete columns if they are left blank. It would really help the readability of this spreadsheet.

Here is a copy of the Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_W8PpwiMa60sPY8YF2pTEx-QPIMexqs5ZizVPiWgxMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!A2:C="",,"¤"&TO_TEXT('Form Responses 1'!A2:C)), " ", "×")),,9^9))&FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT="","¤×","¤"&'Form Responses 1'!D2:AT), " ", "×"), 
 MOD(COLUMN('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT), 4)=0)&FILTER(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT="","¤×","¤"&'Form Responses 1'!D2:AT), 
 MOD(COLUMN('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT)-1, 4)=0)&FILTER(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT="","¤×","¤"&'Form Responses 1'!D2:AT), 
 MOD(COLUMN('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT)-2, 4)=0)&FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!AV2:BA="",,"¤"&TO_TEXT('Form Responses 1'!AV2:BA)), 
 " ", "×")),,9^9))), "¤"), "×", " "), "where not Col4 starts with ' '"))
```

[image]

with conditional formatting:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A1, ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A1)))>1
```

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u-SATLRZ684HSASQQvfA9DBbIpZ-2EekF6StPlG-AJg/edit#gid=331596472)

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!A2:C="",,"¤"&TO_TEXT('Form Responses 1'!A2:C)), " ", "×")),,9^9))&FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT="","¤×","¤"&'Form Responses 1'!D2:AT), " ", "×"), 
 MOD(COLUMN('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT), 4)=0)&FILTER(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT="","¤×","¤"&'Form Responses 1'!D2:AT), 
 MOD(COLUMN('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT)-1, 4)=0)&FILTER(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT="","¤×","¤"&'Form Responses 1'!D2:AT), 
 MOD(COLUMN('Form Responses 1'!D2:AT)-2, 4)=0)&FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 IF('Form Responses 1'!AV2:BA="","¤ ","¤"&TO_TEXT('Form Responses 1'!AV2:BA)), 
 " ", "×")),,9^9))), "¤"), "×", " "), "where not Col4 starts with ' '"))
```

Comment: This worked great at first, but when I added more names, it didn't continue the correct formatting. Not sure why, but all the columns filled in next to the kids' names, and then the address moved over to the phone number column?

Comment: @MeganEllis answer updated. try now

Comment: Yes, all the info lines up in the same columns now. Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the repetitions in the columns to delete? In your screenshot, when a name, phone, or address are repeated in a column to make space for kid's names, the repetition is not shown. In the link though, those show. Can I do that with conditional formatting?

Comment: @MeganEllis yes. repetition is there, but conditional formatting paints all duplicate results with white background and white font so it looks like there isn't anything there

Comment: @MeganEllis did the answer solve your question?